# ModelSerializer error: can't convert model to json

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the following simple serializer for a `User` model to convert it to JSON:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   class Meta:
    model = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
    fields = ('username','email','firstname')

user = UserSerializer(data=User.objects.get(username=serializer.validated_data['user']))
```

when I do `print(user.errors)`. 
I get:

```
{'non_field_errors': ['Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got User.']}
```

Why is it expecting a dictionary and not the model specified in the Meta?

Comment: Are you trying to create the user from validated_data or trying to serialize the existing user instance?

Comment: Serialize an existing user instance.

Comment: then call the serializer like `user = UserSerializer(instance)`. here instance = User.objects.get(username='some username'). then calling user.data will give you the serialized value of the user instance. You need to pass `data` only during creating the user instance.